# Azure Synapse query to multiple JSON files in data lake, parse data into table format

Tags: sql-server, query, json, azure-synapse-analytics, openjson

I want to query RAW telemetry data stored in JSON format in my data lake. I am using Azure Synapse to query the files.

I can successfully pull the data I want into a result table, but I struggle to understand how to take all the rows in the result and apply the JSON -> table transformation across them.

I can successfully do this on 1 row, but when I attempt to do this across multiple, I get the error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I suspect I need a CROSS APPLY, but I'm at the end of my knowledge. Help appreciated.

**QUERY**

```
DECLARE @json2 nvarchar(MAX) = (
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/100/103/xxxx/2023/10/23/*.json',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        FIELDQUOTE = '0x0b',
        FIELDTERMINATOR ='0x0b',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0b'
    )
    WITH (
        json2 varchar(MAX)
    ) AS json2
)
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json2, '$.DeviceId') AS Device, [MeasureType], [MeasureValue],[DataPointTimestamp]
FROM OPENJSON(@json2, '$.MeasureList') WITH (
   [MeasureType] nvarchar(max) '$.MeasureType',
   [MeasureValue] nvarchar(max) '$.MeasureValue',
   [DataPointTimestamp] nvarchar(max) '$.DataPointTimestamp'  
)
```

**DATA Example - 2 rows**

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ {    "DeviceId": "00000",    "MeasureList": [      {        "MeasureType": 24,        "MeasureValue": 23.3,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T09:58:48.2962707+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 7,        "MeasureValue": 5787.0,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T09:58:48.296772+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 3,        "MeasureValue": 2.304,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T09:58:48.296772+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 4,        "MeasureValue": 30.0,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T09:58:48.296772+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 1,        "MeasureValue": 37.0,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T09:58:48.2977765+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 22,        "MeasureValue": 55.0,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T09:58:48.2977765+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 20,        "MeasureValue": 0.0,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T09:58:48.2977765+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 18,        "MeasureValue": 1.0,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T09:58:48.2977765+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 9,        "MeasureValue": -0.112031,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T09:58:48.6572325+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 10,        "MeasureValue": 51.503401,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T09:58:48.6572325+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 8,        "MeasureValue": 28.3871,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T09:58:48.911908+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 17,        "MeasureValue": 49.0,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T09:58:48.911908+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 12,        "MeasureValue": 46369.09568,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T09:58:49.3340307+00:00"      }    ],    "EventList": [],    "InformationList": []  }     ║
║ {    "DeviceId": "0000",    "MeasureList": [      {        "MeasureType": 24,        "MeasureValue": 23.3,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T10:48:48.3482369+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 7,        "MeasureValue": 5811.0,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T10:48:48.3482369+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 3,        "MeasureValue": 2.304,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T10:48:48.3482369+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 4,        "MeasureValue": 30.0,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T10:48:48.3482369+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 1,        "MeasureValue": 34.0,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T10:48:48.3492387+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 22,        "MeasureValue": 55.0,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T10:48:48.3492387+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 20,        "MeasureValue": 0.0,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T10:48:48.3492387+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 18,        "MeasureValue": 1.0,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T10:48:48.3492387+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 9,        "MeasureValue": -0.112204,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T10:48:48.7427858+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 10,        "MeasureValue": 51.503366,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T10:48:48.7427858+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 8,        "MeasureValue": 28.374,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T10:48:48.9999703+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 17,        "MeasureValue": 49.0,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T10:48:48.9999703+00:00"      },      {        "MeasureType": 12,        "MeasureValue": 46369.357824,        "DataPointTimestamp": "2023-10-23T10:48:49.4220929+00:00"      }    ],    "EventList": [],    "InformationList": []  } ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

**Desired result**

```
╔════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════╗
║ Device ║ MeasureType ║ Measure Value ║        DataPointTimestamp         ║
╠════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════════════════════════╣
║   0000 ║          11 ║ 128034.0      ║ 2023-10-23T07:28:30.6775066+00:00 ║
║   0000 ║           6 ║ 8258.0        ║ 2023-10-23T07:28:30.6775066+00:00 ║
║   0000 ║          24 ║ 19.6          ║ 2023-10-23T07:28:30.6775066+00:00 ║
║   0000 ║          11 ║ 11.0          ║ 2023-10-23T07:38:30.6775066+00:00 ║
║   0000 ║           6 ║ 99999         ║ 2023-10-23T07:38:30.6775066+00:00 ║
║   0000 ║          24 ║ 29.6          ║ 2023-10-23T07:38:30.6775066+00:00 ║
╚════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════╝
```